# Drawing a sprite on the circumference of a circle based on the position of other objects

Tags: drawing, trigonometry, game-maker-studio-2

I'm making a sniper shooter arcade style game in Gamemaker Studio 2 and I want the position of targets outside of the viewport to be pointed to by chevrons that move along the circumference of the scope when it moves. I am using trig techniques to determine the coordinates but the chevron is jumping around and doesn't seem to be pointing to the target. I have the code broken into two: the code to determine the coordinates in the step event of the enemies class (the objects that will be pointed to) and a draw event in the same class. Additionally, when I try to rotate the chevron so it also points to the enemy, it doesn't draw at all.

Here's the coordinate algorithm and the code to draw the chevrons, respectively

```
//determine the angle the target makes with the player
delta_x = abs(ObjectPlayer.x - x);  //x axis displacement
delta_y = abs(ObjectPlayer.y - y);  //y axis displacement
angle = arctan2(delta_y,delta_x);   //angle in radians
angle *= 180/pi                     //angle in radians

//Determine the direction based on the larger dimension and 
largest_distance = max(x,y);
plusOrMinus = (largest_distance == x)?
sign(ObjectPlayer.x-x) : sign(ObjectPlayer.y-y);

//define the chevron coordinates
chevron_x = ObjectPlayer.x + plusOrMinus*(cos(angle) + 20);
chevron_y = ObjectPlayer.y + plusOrMinus*(sign(angle) + 20);
```

The drawing code

```
if(object_exists(ObjectEnemy)){
    draw_text(ObjectPlayer.x, ObjectPlayer.y-10,string(angle));
    draw_sprite(Spr_Chevron,-1,chevron_x,chevron_y);
    //sSpr_Chevron.image_angle = angle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code is slightly more complex that it needs to be for this, if you want to draw chevrons pointing towards all enemies, you might as well do that on spot in Draw. And use degree-based functions if you're going to need degrees for drawing anyway

```
var px = ObjectPlayer.x;
var py = ObjectPlayer.y;
with (ObjectEnemy) {
    var angle = point_direction(px, py, x, y);
    var chevron_x = px + lengthdir_x(20, angle);
    var chevron_y = py + lengthdir_y(20, angle);
    draw_sprite_ext(Spr_Chevron, -1, chevron_x, chevron_y, 1, 1, angle, c_white, 1);
}
```

(also see: an almost-decade old [blog post](https://yal.cc/gamemaker-pointing-to-an-off-screen-object/) of mine about doing this while clamping to screen edges instead)

Specific problems with your existing code are:

- Using a single-axis `plusOrMinus` with two axes
- Adding 20 to sine/cosine instead of multiplying them by it
- Trying to apply an angle to `sSpr_Chevron` (?) instead of using draw_sprite_ext to draw a rotated sprite.
- Calculating `largest_distance` based on executing instance's X/Y instead of delta X/Y.